# Adding column and rows with a particular filename at the end of multiple CSV files

Tags: python, csv

My scenario:

I have a folder `Users/kbao/Desktop/dailyfiles/` where I store automatically generated csv files. Once a day a file is being added to this folder and has a date as its name:

```
22-01-2020.csv
23-01-2020.csv
24-01-2020.csv
```

Each file has exactly same columns (id, product name, orders, quantity).

```
id    product name    orders    quantity 
1       guitar           1         4
2       drums            4         7
3      ukulele          13         29
```

I'm aiming to add a column named 'date' as the last column and populate values for each row for each file in the folder `Users/kbao/Desktop/dailyfiles/`.

Would it be possible to do such thing with one python script?

#### Desired output

`22-01-2020.csv`:

```
id    product name    orders    quantity     date
1       guitar           1         4       22-01-2020
2       drums            4         7       22-01-2020
3      ukulele          13         29      22-01-2020
```

`23-01-2020.csv`

```
id    product name    orders    quantity     date
1       case             4         4       23-01-2020
2      keyboard          6         8       23-01-2020
3       piano            3         5       23-01-2020
```

`24-01-2020.csv`:

```
 id    product name    orders    quantity     date
 1       violin           12        24       24-01-2020
 2      strings           40        43       24-01-2020
 3      drum pad          7         13       24-01-2020
```

Comment: _Would it be possible to do such thing with one python script?_ Yes.

Comment: It's sounds like you're basically wanting to add part of the file name to the data in the file. This would require reading the file and writing a replacement for it at the same time, and then replacing the original with the new one. I suggest you try to implement that and _then_ ask a question if you can't get it to work properly. The `csv` module in the standard library would make doing it relatively easy.

Comment: My apologise AMC and @martineau. I suppose to add that I'm just taking my first steps with python and have very little clue how to start, but this part got deleted from my post by accident. So I'm playing with simple scripts and trying to launch them one after another in order to play with some dummy data. Next time I will make sure to add some code to my question, but please be sure that I'm spending hours running scripts and receiving errors. Learning by practicing :)

Comment: Baobab1988: That's why I tried to give you some clues in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do:

```
from pathlib import Path

# set path
csv_paths = Path('csv_files/')

# create new date column and save again
for file in csv_paths.glob('**/*.csv'):
    f = pd.read_csv(file)
    f = f.assign(date = file.stem)
    f.to_csv(f'{file.name}', index=False)

## read all files again together
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path) for path in csv_paths.glob('**/*.csv')])
```